# Routes Resources problems on laravel 10-php 8.2

Tags: php, routes, resources, laravel-10, php-8.2

I have problem with routes if using resource. I upgrade from php 7.4/laravel 7 to php 8.2/laravel 10.

After upgrade all routes error. **target class controller does not exist**

laravel 7 code

```
 Route::get('home', 'HomeController@home');
Route::post('save', 'HomeController@save');
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

laravel 10 code

```
 Route::get('home', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@home');
Route::post('save', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@save');
Route::resource('/admin', 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminController');
```

so i changed my code like above. the route with get & post now already ok, but for the resources still get error **Target class [] does not exist**

i try change using class like this

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
Route::resource('/admin', AdminDocController::class);
```

Routeservicesprovider.php

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to your application's "home" route.
     *
     * Typically, users are redirected here after authentication.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';
    protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, and other route configuration.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
        });

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your routes should look based on the code you've shown.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;

Route::get('home', [HomeController::class, 'home']);
Route::post('save', [HomeController::class, 'save']);
Route::resource('/admin', AdminController::class);
```